# Random Pixels Blink White for 1/60th of a Second

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

I am trying to make single pixels flash for 1/60th of a second and then go away over a 2 second period of time until every single pixel on a 1280x720 screen has flashed white. After 2 seconds have elapsed the screen is all black again for 3 or so seconds before it loops and does it again.

The way I solved it was using this fla another stackoverflow user came up with and I modified that uses movie clips. The problem is it doesn't work to get 921600 movie clips to start randomly. It gets really heavy and slow. See attached file that works with

Anyway! I'm sure there is a super smart way of doing this. I'm a novice. Thanks for any help or suggestions.

fla (cs5)
https://mega.co.nz/#!ERRFiJBJ!VYSaH164BcjD9QIiSdpk8WxFp68dYDC0vWzKySC8rg0

swf
https://mega.co.nz/#!kBoxmJCR!Mx7sHX94-9ch15dKdT8knHRRKRljytZXdOBK-2P-TLQ

best,
Rollin

For the original design of the fla I'm linking to above see the solution by Mahmoud Abd El-Fattah on this link.
[Random Start Times for Move Clips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945698/random-start-times-for-move-clips/14946307#14946307)

Comment: Weird site, it does not accept my FF13 as "acceptable browser", and NO, I don't want to update FF for bells and whistles only. ... Actually, 921600 MCs with a SINGLE dot each is a HUGE overkill, use a single BitmapData (with a Bitmap wrapper) and use `setPixel32()` to change its colors.

Comment: @Vesper Here it is in a dropbox link. I don't think this file is very useful other than seeing what it should look like. I know what I've got is super bulky crazy overkill, but I don't know how to employ this bitmap wrapper you talk about. But thanks for setting in off in a direction. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/753249/exposure7_2.fla
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/753249/exposure7_2.swf

Comment: Start by looking at the BitmapData class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the simplest method will be something like this:

```
static const WIDTH:int=1280;
static const HEIGHT:int=720;
static const WH:int=WIDTH*HEIGHT;
static const FRAMES:int=120; // 2 seconds * 60 frames. Adjust as needed
static var VF:Vector.<int>; // primary randomizer
static var BD:BitmapData; // displayed object
static var curFrame:int; // current frame
static var BDRect:Rectangle;
function init():void {
    // does various inits
    if (!VF) VF=new Vector.<int>(WH,true); // fixed length to optimize memory usage and performance
    if (!BD) BD=new BitmapData(WIDTH,HEIGHT,false,0); // non-transparent bitmap
    BDRect=BD.rect;
    BD.fillRect(BDRect,0); // for transparent BD, fill with 0xff000000
    curFrame=-1;
    for (var i:int=0;i<WH;i++) VF[i]=Math.floor(Math.random()*FRAMES); // which frame will have the corresponding pixel lit white
}
function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    curFrame++;
    BD.lock();
    BD.fillRect(BDRect,0);
    if ((curFrame>=0)&&(curFrame<FRAMES)) {
        // we have a blinking frame
        var cw:int=0;
        var ch:int=0;
        for (var i:int=0;i<WH;i++) {
            if (VF[i]==curFrame) BD.setPixel(cw,ch,0xffffff);
            cw++; // next column. These are to cache, not calculate
            if (cw==WIDTH) { cw=0; ch++; } // next row
        }
    } else if (curFrame>FRAMES+20) {
        // allow the SWF a brief black period. If not needed, check for >=FRAMES
        init(); 
    }
    BD.unlock();
}
function Main() {
    init();
    addChild(new Bitmap(BD));
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame);
}
```

Comment: Hey. I'm totally stupid and actually have no idea how to employ the code you wrote. It looks like it makes sense and the comments look like they'd be useful if I could make it work.

Do I put that on a blank key frame? Do I need to import a single pixel image or something? Sorry, I'm totally  new to this stuff.

Comment: Well, a BitmapData is already made of pixels. This code can be placed inside a class or on a keyframe, in case of a keyfrawe you have to either call `Main()` or drop the `function Main() {` and `}` lines, so that the code inside will execute once. It's better to place this code into a class that extends `Sprite`, so that `Main()` will be its constructor (rename the function for this), and call `addChild(new MyBlinkingStuff());`